# Java (ArrayList)

Tags: java

The following method should returns the length of the longest sorted sequence within a list of integers. For example, if a variable called list stores the following sequence of values: `{11,12,30,41,5,3,7,6}`, it should return `4`.

When the longest sorted sequence starts at front, this method fails the test(it returns `3`), but it  works for the other tests. Does anybody know where the problem is? Thank you.

```
public int longestSortedSequence() {

    int count = 0;
    int max1 = 0;
                int max2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (elementData[i] <= elementData[i + 1]) {
            count++;
            if (count >= max1) {
                max1 = count;

            }
        } else if (elementData[i] > elementData[i + 1]) {
            count = 0;
            count++;
            if (count >= max2) {
                max2 = count;
            }
        }
    }
    return Math.max(max1, max2);
}
```

Comment: Why is this marked both Java and C# ?

Comment: How is elementData declared?  What does this have to do with ArrayList?

Comment: public class ArrayIntList {
    private int[] elementData;
    private int size;

    
}

Comment: What's the point of taking the max between max and max?

Comment: If you have 4 elements in order you will have element N compare smaller than element N+1 3 times.

Comment: count >= max can probably be count > max

Comment: to find the longest sequence.

Comment: Why do you increment count in the `>` case?

Comment: We know the purpose is to find the longest sequence.  But why take the max between max and max???  (Other than your instructor told you to use that function.)

Comment: to count the numbers in each sequence.

Comment: You're not making sense.  THINK about what each step does.  "Execute" it in your mind (or on paper).  Insert System.out.println calls to follow what it's actually doing.  Do some actual debugging.

Comment: When I change it to max1 and max2, I still get the same answer.

Comment: Please quit being an idiot and consider what we're saying.  Up until now we were trying to help you.

Comment: One last hint:  Feed in the array `[1,2,3,4]` and see what happens.

Comment: You don't need second `if` in `if (elementData[i] <= elementData[i + 1]) {...} else **if** (elementData[i] > elementData[i + 1]) {...}` since if it is not `<=` then it has no other choice than being `>`. Change it to `if (elementData[i] <= elementData[i + 1]) {...} else {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two comments:

1. For each `i`, you are testing whether element `i+1` continues the current non-decreasing sequence. So, before the first iteration of your loop, you should already have counted element 0 as belonging to the current non-decreasing sequence; on the first iteration, you test if element 1 continues that sequence. That means `count` should be set to 1 in the beginning.
2. Your code will probably throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on the last iteration of the for loop, because `i+1` will equal size, which is not a valid index into your array.

Answer (score 0):

- I guess the codes in your question  were with a lot of copy-paste. e.g. the  `if (count>=max)` parts.
- Your codes may throw `IndexOutOfBoundExcep.` because you read `e[i+1]` in your loop, and set with condition `i<size`
- The `count` should be at least 1. (descending sort case), if the array is not empty. When empty array, return 0.

I just did some fixes, and re-wrote a bit. (without writing in IDE, not tested either). Just show some idea.

```
public int longestSortedSequence() {
    if (size==0)return 0; //empty array
    int count = 1; //at least 1
    int max = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++) {
        if (elementData[i] <= elementData[i + 1]) {
            count++;          
        } else {
            max=count>max?count:max;
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    return count>max? count: max;
}
```